# Failure syncing Gradle

Tags: android, git, gradle

I've had a problem - I couldn't open 'Project Structure'.
I had an error showing up :

```
IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4 and 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4
```

Then I deleted some folders inside the sdk/build-tools. After that I started receiving this message :
[image]

I reinstalled Android Studio, but I get the same error now. It appears it somehow restored the folders before the uninstall, since I can see, for example, that a folder named '23.0.3' is in the build-tools folder and its creation time is before the uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy your gladle file.

Try to put

```
 compileSdkVersion 24
 buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
```

In your .gradle file in android section instead of 24.0.0-rc3

Comment: Before I could do what you wrote, I've tried setting in project structure the Compile Sdk Version to 6.0(Marshmallow) and now some other problems occurs. I've edited my post and posted the screenshot

Comment: Your Android section config should look like this:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 100
        versionName "0.1"
    }
}


Without looking at the code I can't say why Android section is recognised as DSL method

Comment: did that.. still getting that "Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' ...

Comment: Is this section in your Android app level build.gradle or in the project top level build.gradle where buildscript section is located by default?

Comment: app level build.gradle

Comment: ok so I've fixed that Gradle DSL issue. But I still have the original issue.
I have ` compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"` but it didn't fix the issue.. I have this "Install Build Tools 24.0.0 rc3 and sync project`